# Django. Пару вопросов про внедрение и сопровождение(новичек)

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.
Изучаю и уже делаю свои простые проекты. Пользуюсь Джанго 1.8 на питон 3.
Вопросы:

1) Для реализации проекта не в локальной среде джанго, а уже на боевой машине, например есть собственный сервер в компании, мне потребуется установить только лишь интерпритатор Python/Django соответствующей версии и базу данных для того, чтобы проект функцианировал?

2) Есть ли возможность в уже готовый сайт, например написанный на коленке html страничками или же на CMS ке с PHP, внедрить моq Django проект? Уточню... позволит ли сервер на котором стоит сайт установить Django/Python интерпритатор и понимать мой проект паралельно с PHP или прочим "хламом"?

Часто ли при реализации уже на боевых серверах возникают проблемы с реализацией? Поправьте меня пожалуйста если я в чем-то не прав.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Для реализации проекта на боевом сервере команда manage.py runserver не подойдет. Помимо настройки базы данных, установки python, django и других необходимых пакетов, Вам необходимо будет:

- установить веб-сервер (Nginx или Apache) - он будет управлять запросами, раздавать статику, перенаправлять запросы на uwsgi/gunicorn (см. ниже)
- запустить uwsgi или gunicorn для работы непосредственно с python-проектом, так как nginx/apache не умеет напрямую работать с Питоном.

Подробности в [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/), хорошая статья также есть на [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) для связки nginx + uwsgi на ubuntu 14.04 (на этом же сайте есть и другие подробные описания способов настройки запуска django-приложений), также есть русская статья на [habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/226419/).

2) Исходя из написанного выше: Вам все равно нужен будет веб-сервер, а он может работать и с php/раздавать html. Правда, работать в данном случае придется уже с двумя проектами - что обычно довольно затратно.

Если у Вас все на html - перенести на django очень просто: в папку templates кидаете все html-файлы, которые отдаете во вьюхах, в папку static - все остальное (останется только поправить пути файлов, но это не большая проблема).
Если все на php - просто настраиваете nginx/apache, чтобы определенные запросы (в зависимости от url) отправлялись на django или CMS на php (в зависимости от требований). Если нужна сложная интеграция (например - общая корзина для обоих проектов - если это магазин, или общая авторизация) - то обычно проще сделать перенос всего проекта на django, хотя и в этом случае можно сделать так, чтобы все работало (django умеет исполнять работать с несколькими БД, и также исполнять raw sql).

Answer (score 0):

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/
2. Можно все, что угодно, вот только зачем